# sitemap with duplicate urls and querystring values

Tags: asp.net

We had the following in our website.sitemap file

> ```
>   <siteMapNode url="~/admin/NewSub.aspx" title="New Subs" >
>     <siteMapNode url="~/admin/Request.aspx" title="Request Details"  queryStringToInclude="rid">
>       <siteMapNode url="~/admin/Preview.aspx" title="Preview"   queryStringToInclude="rid"/>
>       <siteMapNode url="~/admin/EditRequest.aspx" title="Edit Request"  queryStringToInclude="rid"/>
>     </siteMapNode>
>   </siteMapNode>
>   <siteMapNode url="~/admin/Notices.aspx" title="Notices">
>     <siteMapNode url="~/admin/RequestDetails.aspx" title="Request Details"  queryStringToInclude="rid">
>     </siteMapNode>
>   </siteMapNode>
> ```

I need to include RequestDetail.aspx twice, as there are two ways to get to the same page, but doing so results in an duplicate error, can't have the same url in different Nodes.  So I updated the 2nd one to be url="~/admin/RequestDetails.aspx?id=1" and queryStringToInclude="id,rid"

We are using a CustomProvider, as we need querystrings to append to the values in the sitemap.  Is there any way to get it so that in the SmartSiteMapProvider_SiteMapResolve method the code will know which one to pick.  We initially had:

> SiteMapNode temp = null;
>       temp = SiteMap.Providers["SiteMap"].CurrentNode.Clone(true);

but that would always result in "New Subs" being the currentnode, I updated the code to incldue the following check:

> ```
>         if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
>         {
>             temp = SiteMap.Providers["SiteMap"].FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("/testapp/admin/requestdetails.aspx?id=1").Clone(true);
>         }
> ```

that seems to work, but it's hardcoding the check for that specific url,  is there a better way to do this?